# Adding custom ItemListener with EventHandler

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jcombobox, itemlistener

I would like to add an `ItemListener` to a `JComboBox`, but with using the nifty `EventHandler`.

Something like this:

```
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            // Do something
        }
    }   
});
```

in the form of:

```
comboBox.addItemListener((ItemListener)EventHandler.create(ItemListener.class, target, method, event));
```

and then having a pulic method:

```
public void myMethod(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I do something alike with my buttons and thought it would be very nice to do the same with more complex events like this. Is it possible?

Comment: *"Is it possible?"* Yes, is it a good idea, probably not. Most listeners have more then one event callback, the solution would invoke reflection which needs careful consideration in its use as it not only has performance ramifications but also refactoring issues

Comment: I would also not recommend using it because of Reflection/Proxy abuses, as well as refactoring issues as already said by @MadProgrammer.

Comment: As long as it's not recommended, it doesn't really matter if it's possible or not. Thank you, guys!